# Adal Angular5 Adal5Service.acquireToken falls with "Token renewal operation failed due to timeout", but there are successful requests in network

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, angular5, adal, adal.js

Try to use [adal-angular5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/adal-angular5) and have problem with `Adal5Service.acquireToken` method: it is always falls with:

> Token renewal operation failed due to timeout

Online full example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-96tws9?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts). To test:

- paste your tenant
- paste your clientId
- register URL `https://angular-96tws9.stackblitz.io` in [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com/) for your app
- open in new window

Here is `app.component.ts`:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Adal5Service } from 'adal-angular5';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private adalSvc: Adal5Service) {
    let config: adal.Config = {
      tenant: 'XXX.onmicrosoft.com',
      clientId: '21efffd5-29fc-XXX',
      postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin,
      endpoints: {
        graphApiUri: "https://graph.microsoft.com",
      },
      cacheLocation: "localStorage",
      redirectUri: ''
    };

    this.adalSvc.init(config);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.adalSvc.handleWindowCallback();

    if (!this.adalSvc.userInfo.authenticated) {
      this.adalSvc.login();
      return;
    }

    // work correct
    console.log(this.adalSvc.userInfo.username);

    this.adalSvc.acquireToken("https://graph.microsoft.com")
      .subscribe(
        token => console.log(token), // never comes
        error => console.log(error)); // error: Token renewal operation failed due to timeout
  }
}
```

There are correct acquired token In network:
[image]

Error on page
[image]

Here is `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "angular-template",
  "description": "",
  "homepage": "https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-96tws9",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "5.0.0",
    "core-js": "2.5.1",
    "rxjs": "5.5.2",
    "zone.js": "0.8.18",
    "adal-angular5": "1.0.36"
  },
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.5.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.0.4",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `package.json`?

Comment: @Milo, added package.json. Also [full online demo example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-96tws9?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally get it working, without [adal-angular5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/adal-angular5) library.
Here is [full example](https://github.com/AlexeyBoiko/angular5-office365-adal-example) of

- authorize user
- acquire token for Microsoft Graph Api
- get user messages from Microsoft Graph Api
- silence renew token

Example use only standard [Adal.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js) (without wrappers) and typings from [@types/adal-angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/adal-angular).

Angular routs is working. Also, there are no double requests when renewing token.

Comment: I am having the same issue. I have tried your solution, but it did not work for me. Do you have any updates that you have not applied to your github solution? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's your implementation but it seems other people are having [this issue](https://github.com/grumar/adal-angular5/issues) as well. [This issue](https://github.com/sureshchahal/angular2-adal/issues/85) on [ng2-adal](https://github.com/sureshchahal/angular2-adal) states that there is an issue w/ `acquireToken()` for `adal-angular@1.0.16` (read last comment).

[adal-angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/adal-angular) is the underlying package for both of those adal implementations. I ran into this myself using `ng2-adal` and downgraded to `adal-angular@1.0.14` and got `acquireToken()` to work. Not sure how `adal-angular5` handles this though.

[Here](https://github.com/krzyhook/angular-adal-example) is example I used with `ng2-adal` package (using Angular/.NET Core) and [another](https://github.com/ranveeraggarwal/angular-adal-quickstart) (standalone) if you are looking to try `ng2-adal`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The error is from the reference of dependency : adal-angular
In library adal-angular5 the depency is not good. 
You don't have to restart with adal-angular.
This topic save my day : [benbaran issue comment](https://github.com/benbaran/adal-angular4/issues/47#issuecomment-396080730/%22issue%20comment%22)